# bizarre ActiveRecord equality issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, equality

I've fixed this for my actual app fairly trivially by overriding the == operator, but it is driving me nuts and I haven't been able to find an explanation. As far as I know, ActiveRecord is supposed to determine the equality of two existing records just via the id field, right?

Apparently, no!

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.4)
irb(main):001:0> c = ChallengeClaim.find(1)
=> #<ChallengeClaim id: 1, collection_id: 954, creation_id: nil, creation_type: nil, request_signup_id: 2, request_prompt_id: 5, claiming_user_id: 8, sent_at: nil, fulfilled_at: nil, defaulted_at: nil, created_at: "2011-09-23 04:39:07", updated_at: "2011-09-23 04:39:07">
irb(main):002:0> c2 = ChallengeClaim.find(2)
=> #<ChallengeClaim id: 2, collection_id: 954, creation_id: nil, creation_type: nil, request_signup_id: 2, request_prompt_id: 4, claiming_user_id: 8, sent_at: nil, fulfilled_at: nil, defaulted_at: nil, created_at: "2011-11-07 17:47:33", updated_at: "2011-11-07 17:47:33">
irb(main):003:0> c == c2
=> true
```

?!?!!??!

Any explanations gratefully welcomed so I can sleep at night again. :>

Comment: Have you implemented `def <=>(other)` on `ChallengeClaim` somewhere?

Comment: have you customized your primary key in your model definition? Equality of ActiveRecord objects is done by comparing the identity column/attribute of the objects. It's not a attribute by attribute comparison. At least that's my understanding...

Comment: Chris that was totally it. *facepalms* Want to post that as an answer so I can confirm it?

Answer (score 0):

As Chris Heald pointed out above in the comments, indeed the comparison operator <=> was defined on ChallengeClaim!